# Using Fn::Sub with a common string in a Cloud Formation Template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm struggling a little with `Fn::Sub` and `Fn::FindInMap` in order to create a dynamic value for a resource.

I would like something in the mapping like

```yaml
Mappings:
  Mapping01:
    common:
      SyncName: "archive-uploader-${AWS::Region}-synchronisation-a2"
```

Then I'd like to use it something like

```yaml
Name: !Sub !FindInMap [Mapping01, common, SyncName]
```

Which I know I can't do because the Sub function cannot take intrinsic functions at the String parameter. But I cannot see a neat way to do this. At the moment I just use Sub and the hardcoded string where I need it.

I'd prefer to have a single place for the string and then use it with Sub where I need it. How can I do that in a CFT?

I don't want to have a large map that just varies the name's region. That's what most of the documentation shows.

Comment: A few issues on GitHub suggest this is a pain point of CloudFormation at the moment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/91

Comment: How did it go?  Still unclear why you can't do this and what could be done about it?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out you can't do this in plain CFN. Your only options to work around this is through development of [CFN macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Alternative is simply not to use CFN,  there are far superior IaC tools (terraform, AWS CDK), pre-process all templates before applying them, or keep hardcoding these values in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could build it up in pieces a little differently and avoid a per-region map. Wouldn't something like this work?

```
Mappings:
  Mapping01:
    common:
      SyncName: synchronisation-a2

...

Resources:
  MyResource:
    Type: AWS::whatever
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub
        - "archive-uploader-{region}-{suffix}"
        - region: !Ref AWS::Region
          suffix: !FindInMap [Mapping01, common, SyncName]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `- "archive-uploader-${region}-${suffix}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward to do.  You would need the advanced form of `Fn::Sub`

First though:

- if this string will remain same for all regions, you should make the common name a parameter, not a mapping.
- if it will change per region, then create 2 parameters to hold the b4 and after strings .. `I have assumed this is your use case, in my example below`

```
Parameters:
  String1:
    Type: String
    Default: "archive-uploader-"
  String2:
    Type: String
    Default: "-synchronisation-a2"

Resources:

Name:
  Fn::Sub:
    - "${str1}${reg}${str2}${finmap}"  #these are just placeholder formats
    - str1: !Ref String1
      reg: !Ref AWS::Region
      str2: !Ref String2
      finmap: !FindInMap [MapName, MapRootKey, MapValueKey]
```

- I hope I read your needs correctly, but in general you can then mix values coming from dynamic vars, from parameters and even from some mappings .. as required.
- You could probably do same with `!Join` but it may be more convoluted